# How to mention my class rank in my CV

Tags: cv, grading, ranking

If I graduated from a university (named `X` for example) in 2014 and my average (or GPA) was the highest among all students who graduated that year from the same major (let's call it Y). So I want to say in my CV that my rank was the first. How to say that in a proffesional way?

What I'm currently using:

> Graduated from X with a B.Sc degree in Y with an average of 90% (class rank: 1)

Comment: What you've written is misleading, in my opinion. "Class rank: 1" makes me think you had the highest GPA in your entire undergraduate college, not just in your major.

Comment: What do you suggest to remove this misleadingness?

Comment: To remove the ambiguity, use: *Graduated from X with a B.Sc degree in Y with an average of 90% (Y class rank: 1)*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you have looks fine to me.  I've seen numerous cv's with notation like that and never thought amiss of them.

Answer (score 5):

Realistically, it's your CV and you can do anything you like.  And people do.

A common format for an entry in the education section of a CV is *degree honors, major, university, month year*.  If your university recognized your rank as first in the class as valedictorian or perhaps summa cum laude, I would probably write it this way and skip the GPA.

> B.Sc valedictorian, Y, University of X, June 2014.

If they didn't recognize your performance with a specific designation of honors, I might add the additional information in parens following.

> B.Sc, Y, University of X, June 2014.  (GPA 90%, Class rank 1)

But again, it's your CV and there are no hard and fast rules.